# What can be explanation for anamolus behavior of graph of equation $y=xy\cos(9^{f(x,y)})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

I was playing with graphs of desmos graph plotter and found this function
$$y=xy\cos(9^{f(x,y)})$$

[image: the graphs]

If i substitute $f(x,y)$ with any function in $x$, $y$ i get some scattered points creating the function graph much more better illustration in graph picture what could be the reason for this is it some technical problem or something?

Comment: Since you did not provide any proof in your question, why are you using the `proof-explanation` tag?

Comment: Sorry i have edited now

Comment: You have at first an implicitly defined function of two variables. Later you construct two different equations (or two different functions of one variable). It seems there are two different questions.